# How to set the Selected Item's text color in Html.Listbox

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, listbox

I can't seem to find anything on the internet regarding this, when I do it is only regarding WPF.

How do I set the Selected Item's text color in a Html.Listbox.
Not talking about the highligted color of a selected item, but the **text color** of a **selected** item.

Here is my code, I am using asp.net-mvc.

```
<div style="display: inline-block; width: 265px;">
Blocked 
<br />
<%=Html.ListBox("blockedNumbers", Model.Version.AvailableInBook.Where(ac => ac.Status 
== NumberCountryStatusEnum.Blocked).Select(status => new SelectListItem
   {
     Selected = false,
     Value = status.CountryInfo.Code,
     Text = status.CountryInfo.Tel
   }), new { id = "blockedNumbers", style = "height: 160px; width: 260px;margin: 5px 5px 10px 0;" })%>
```

I probably have to change it in the style, but don't know what attribute.

Thanks a million in advance

Comment: Set the `color` property in the `style` attribute.

Comment: I did and it changes the text color indeed, but when you select an Item by the browser(IE) default it changes the highlight color to blue and the text color to white and the white text color is what I want to change.

Comment: Add " !important" after the color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text color in css style attributes are set using the `color: <value>;` attribute, have you tried adding that to your style value?

For the "selected" option (and not the highlighted) you could solve it with css by using the "option:checked" specifier, but you cannot set this with inline style.

```
#blockedNumbers option:checked { color: #ff0000; }
```

Or use jquery as follows: http://jsfiddle.net/zNTqm/458/ or

Comment: I did and it changes the text color indeed, but when you select an Item by the browser(IE) default it changes the highlight color to blue and the text color to white and the white text color is what I want to change.